# The list of my third party apps in settings app is hidden

Tags: ios, settings

Where is the following part of settings app?;)

[image]

I have developed the app with settings.bundle but some of my users could not see the settings for any of their app.

Is there an option to turn it on? Shouldn't it be visible always?

Under the 'Vimeo' there is nothing more for some of users.

Comment: I encountere this issue sometimes so it's probably not app-related. Usually terminating the Settings app or rebooting the phone fixes it. Does this not solve the problem for your users?

Comment: I will try and let you know...